# How to block all incoming calls and text messages in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am implementing blocker app work is almost done but when we install true caller app then incoming call is seen in log. Please tell me how to set maximum priority.
My code is given below where I am wrong please tell me.

```
package com.rsoft.callBlockerService;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.rsoft.callBlockerActivities.CallBlockerMainActivity;
import com.rsoft.callListener.ServiceReciever;
import com.rsoft.callblocker.R;
import com.rsoft.messageListener.SmsReceiver;
import com.rsoft.notificationCenter.CallBlockerToastNotification;
import com.rsoft.objects.BlockedContact;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallBlockerService extends Service {

    public static final int notification_id = 111;

    // ---------------------------------------
    // Listening Services
    // ---------------------------------------
    private static ServiceReciever service;
    private static SmsReceiver sms;

    // ---------------------------------------
    // Data Structures
    // ---------------------------------------
    public static HashMap<String, BlockedContact> blackList;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        loadData();
        service = new ServiceReciever(getApplicationContext());
        sms = new SmsReceiver();
/*      IntentFilter intentCall = new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        intentCall.setPriority(999);
        registerReceiver(service, intentCall);*/
        registerReceiver(service, new IntentFilter(
                "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
        IntentFilter intentSMS = new IntentFilter(
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        intentSMS.setPriority(2147483647);
        registerReceiver(sms, intentSMS);
        // registerReceiver(sms, new
        // IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
        String android_id = Secure.getString(getBaseContext()
                .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        final BlockedContact cn=CallBlockerService.blackList.get(android_id);
        if (cn.getName().equals("0")) {
            showStatusBarNotification("Text Off app is running now");
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //CallBlockerToastNotification
            //  .showDefaultShortNotification("Text Off App Stop");
        service.stopListening();
        unregisterReceiver(service);
        unregisterReceiver(sms);
        service = null;
        sms = null;
        cancelStatusBarNotification();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void showStatusBarNotification(String message) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(CallBlockerService.this,
                CallBlockerMainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Text Off notification")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.running_not_icon).setContentIntent(pi)
                .build();

        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        manager.notify(notification_id, noti);
    }

    public void cancelStatusBarNotification() {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(notification_id);
    }

    public void loadData() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("CallBlocker.data");
            ObjectInputStream objeto = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            blackList = (HashMap<String, BlockedContact>) objeto.readObject();
            fis.close();
            objeto.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            blackList = new HashMap<String, BlockedContact>();
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

Edited:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".MySMSReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**MySMSReceiver.class Extends BroadcastReceiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    _context = context;
    if(intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        SmsMessage smsMessage;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            SmsMessage[] msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            smsMessage = msgs[0];
        } else {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        }
        String numberMNS = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

        if (smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().contains("Accept me n:")) {
            String[] parse = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().split("Accept me n:");
            String Nuevonombre = parse[1];
            if (Nuevonombre.length() > 3){
                saveContact(Nuevonombre,numberMNS);
            }else{
                ctx.sendSMS(numberMNS,"Your name must be more than 4 characters.");
            }
        } else {
            boolean check = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ctx.numbersAdded.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    String num = ctx.numbersAdded.getString(i);
                    if (num.equals(numberMNS)){
                        check = true;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (!check){
                abortBroadcast();
                ctx.sendSMS(numberMNS, "To contact me, send: Accept me n: your full name.");
            }

        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "DONT WORK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Main.class**

```
MySMSReceiver mns = new MySMSReceiver();
mns.ctx = this;
registerReceiver(mns, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

**CALLS**

**CallHelper.class**

```
interface BackBoolean{
    void returns(boolean check);
}

class CheckPhoneBlock{
    protected void Y(JSONArray conts,String search, BackBoolean call) throws JSONException{
        boolean checkbool = false;
        Log.w("Phones",conts.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < conts.length();i++){
            String phone = conts.getString(i);
            if (phone.contains(search)){
                checkbool = true;
            }
        }
        call.returns(checkbool);
    }
}

public class CallHelper {

    private MainActivity ctx;
    private TelephonyManager tm;
    private CallStateListener callStateListener;

    private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;
    private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, final String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                    try{
                        JSONArray countacts = ctx.contacts.allcontacts;
                        new CheckPhoneBlock().Y(countacts, incomingNumber, new BackBoolean() {
                            @Override
                            public void returns(boolean check) {
                                if (check) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Incoming: " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    disconnectCall();
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject newbloqreg = new JSONObject();
                                        newbloqreg.put("name","Bloqueado");
                                        newbloqreg.put("number",incomingNumber);

                                        JSONObject his = ctx.data.getJSONObject("history");
                                        JSONArray llamadas = his.getJSONArray("llamadas");
                                        llamadas.put(newbloqreg);
                                        his.put("llamadas",llamadas);
                                        ctx.data.put("history",his);
                                        ctx.saveDB();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void disconnectCall(){
        try {
            String serviceManagerName = "android.os.ServiceManager";
            String serviceManagerNativeName = "android.os.ServiceManagerNative";
            String telephonyName = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            Class<?> telephonyStubClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerClass;
            Class<?> serviceManagerNativeClass;
            Method telephonyEndCall;
            Object telephonyObject;
            Object serviceManagerObject;
            telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephonyName);
            telephonyStubClass = telephonyClass.getClasses()[0];
            serviceManagerClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerName);
            serviceManagerNativeClass = Class.forName(serviceManagerNativeName);
            Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
            Method tempInterfaceMethod = serviceManagerNativeClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Binder tmpBinder = new Binder();
            tmpBinder.attachInterface(null, "fake");
            serviceManagerObject = tempInterfaceMethod.invoke(null, tmpBinder);
            IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerObject, "phone");
            Method serviceMethod = telephonyStubClass.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            telephonyObject = serviceMethod.invoke(null, retbinder);
            telephonyEndCall = telephonyClass.getMethod("endCall");
            telephonyEndCall.invoke(telephonyObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("FUCK", "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
            Log.w("FUCK", "Exception object: " + e);
        }
    }

    public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Outgoing: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    public CallHelper(MainActivity ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
        outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
    }


    public void start() {
        Log.w("START","BROAD");
        tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
        ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    public void stop() {
        tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
    }
```

**Main.class**

```
CallHelper call = new CallHelper(this);
call.start();
```